# Fetch correct overload method with Reflection based on arguments

Tags: c#, overloading, system.reflection

Suppose I have a method with many overloads, such as `Console.WriteLine`, which I want to fetch via Reflection. I have a `dynamic` value `x` and want to fetch the most relevant method for `x`'s type, like this:

```
var consoleType = Type.GetType("System.Console")

dynamic x = "Foo";
GetMethodFromParams(consoleType, "WriteLine", new[] {x}); // => [Void WriteLine(string)]

x = 3;
GetMethodFromParams(consoleType, "WriteLine", new[] {x}); // => [Void WriteLine(int)]

x = new SomeClass();
GetMethodFromParams(consoleType, "WriteLine", new[] {x}); // => [Void WriteLine(object)]
```

From what I can see, you can only fetch a method if you know the parameter types of the method, otherwise an exception is thrown:

```
> Type.GetType("System.Console").GetMethod("WriteLine")
Ambiguous match found.
  + System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(string, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions, System.Type[], System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[])
  + System.Type.GetMethod(string)

> Type.GetType("System.Console").GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { Type.GetType("System.String") })
[Void WriteLine(System.String)]
```

How could I implement the `GetMethodFromParams` method demonstrated above? One idea I had was using the `Type.GetType(...).GetMethods()` method and filtering through the results based on their parameter types compared to `x`'s type, but this might be tricky to get working with covariance and contravariance.

Comment: Did you try to use `GetType()` for dynamic? `Dynamic` object is `System.Object` and has method `GetType`, but compiler doesn't know about it. I mean `consoleType.GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { x.GetType() as Type })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can simply use `x.GetType()` to get `x`'s type and pass that as an array element to `GetMethod` and it works great, even for covariance and contravariance. This means you could implement this like so:

```
public static MethodInfo GetMethodFromParams(Type t, string methodName, dynamic[] args)
    => t.GetMethod(methodName,
           args.Select(x => (Type)x.GetType())
               .ToArray());
```